# How Can I Add A Derived Class To Repository

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository

I need an advice.
I have two class and one ofe them a derived class.
**I want to insert my base and derived class in a one method**. How can i accomplish this?

```
//my entities
public class Form
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnForm : Form
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

//my repository
public class FormRepository : IFormRepository:IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;

    public FormRepository(MyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    
    //I want to insert here Form or ReturnForm objects.
    //What can i do?
    public void AddFormMessage(Form form)
    {
        _db.Forms.Add(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your dbContext pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem in business layer.

```
public void AddFormMessage<T>(FormDto formDto)
{
    Form form;
    var targetClassType = typeof(T);

    if (targetClassType == typeof(Form))
    {
        form = _mapper.Map<Form>(formDto);
    }
    else if (targetClassType == typeof(ReturnForm))
    {
        form = _mapper.Map<ReturnForm>(formDto);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unknown form type");
    }
    
    _unitOfWork.FormRepository.AddFormMessage(form);
}
```